# Sprockets::FileNotFound; couldn't find file 'selectize.source.css'

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets, selectize.js

I have recently upgraded my app from Rails `4.2.6` to Rails `5.2.3`.

I followed the procedure as on [Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Now, when I try to start my **development server**, it starts without any error.
But when I hit the URL in the browser an error comes up which says:

**Sprockets::FileNotFound in UserSessions#new**

```
Showing /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

couldn't find file 'selectize.source.css'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/config
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/font-awesome
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/fonts
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/images
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/pranjal/source/my-app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  ...
```

```
Extracted source (around line #5):

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>            
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like issue of incompatibility between `js` and new version of `rails` try to use/upgrade `selectize-rails` gem and remove `js` and `css` files from repo (if exists).